# How to display / include a specific jpg on a page

Tags: images, include

is it possible to show / include a specific jpg on a WordPress page?
I have made 365 jpg's, one for each day of the year and want to display the jpg belonging to that day of the year on the specific date. The jpg's are named mmdd.jpg

The PHP code to generate the name is `$a = date(md).".jpg";`

Files are stored in httpdocs\images

Comment: Of course it is. Where are your images stored?

Comment: httpdocs\images

Comment: Outside of the WordPress root folder?

Comment: it says root directory > httpdocs > images; can move the images if easier

Comment: One more question: is this part of a specific theme or do you want it to work with any theme?

Answer (score 1):

To load images from the location you currently have them stored use [`get_site_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url) to generate a path:

```
$a = date('md').".jpg";
$a = get_site_url(null,'images/'.$a);
// var_dump($a);
```

Then use that information to [create an `img` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

I would recommend loading the images from a theme folder, if this is part of a particular theme. If that is the case use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead. If this is part of a plugin, use [`plugins_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)